# twitter bootstrap tooltip not working in js template

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I ma using twitter bootstrap tooltip functionality which works fine in gsp header texts.
Now I want to add bootstrap tooltip on id="tooltipcheck". If I write title="{{data}}" then I could see the tooltip but bootstrap tooltip does not seem to work here.
Is there any issue with js template or there is something else?

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4" id="tooltipcheck" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-original-title="{{data}}">{{data}} </div>
</div>
```

I am calling tooltip like this.

```
      <script>

jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#tooltipcheck").tooltip('show');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the ID of an element in a template because ID's need to be unique. Try changing `tooltipcheck` to a class instead:

`<div class="span4 tooltipcheck" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-original-title="{{data}}">{{data}} </div>`

And then initialize your tooltips using the class:

```
$(".tooltipcheck").tooltip('show');
```

The tooltips will need to be initialized after handlebars has parsed the template and generated your markup, or else the tooltips won't have any elements to bind to.

Comment: You're sure that your tooltips are initializing after handlerbars has generated your markup?

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: Not sure; I've never worked with handlebars before, but I'm guessing you have to call some javascript to get it to read the template and inject the generated HTML into the page. You should initialize your tooltips after that.

Answer (score 0):

since you are working with dynamic elements, after the elements are added to the dom you need to initialize the tooltip for the new elements

Ex:

```
var html = // html from template
var el = $(html).appendTo('somele');
el.find('<tooltip-element>').tooltip('show');
```

Also since you are using a template I'm assuming there will be multiple instances of the template in the page, so do not use `id` inside the template since in dom an id should be present only once

Comment: Sorry .. but I am new to this.. how should I get // html from template... & then should I append to existing div tag?

Comment: @user1298426 please share the code where the template is used

Comment: I am not sure how much it will be useful... but I shared some part related to js template and tooltip. http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav14u/whrUP/1/